# Screen goes blank at 4K 120Hz, when GPU memory clock is <100%

Tags: display, xrandr, radeon

I have the weirdest issue.

When I set `xrandr` to display on my TV at 4K 120Hz, the screen goes blank as soon as anything remotely graphically demanding happens (like switching to overview or moving windows).
When the picture is stationary, or I move my mouse around, or type in the terminal, it's ok.

Here's the weird part: this only happens if my GPU memory clock is not pinned at 100% (as shown in `radeontop`).

Until a few days ago, my GPU memory clock would always be pinned to 100%. I tried looking into it, but it never really bothered me, so I quickly gave up.
Now, when I use my TV, the memory clock is varying, as it should (I think; it does the same at 60Hz, and then there is no black screen).

Here's the funny part:, if I enable both of my 4K 60Hz displays alongside the TV, the clock gets pinned to 100% and the TV runs fine at 4K 120Hz...

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCha_3QGUSY).

How do I even approach troubleshooting this?

Fedora 37 (I'm gonna try to update to 38 right now),
Radeon 6700 XT,
xorg (same problem in Wayland).